# Read delimited text files dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to read a textfile dynamically based on the headers. Consider an example like this

```
name|email|phone|othername|company
john|john@example.com|1234||example
doe|doe@example.com||pin
jane||98485|
```

The values to be read like this for the following records

```
name  email               phone  othername  company
john  john@example.com    1234              example
doe   doe@example.com              pin        
jane                      98485
```

I tried using this

```cs
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(textFile)))
{
while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
{
       string line = sr.ReadLine(); //Using readline method to read text file.
       string[] strlist = line.Split('|'); //using string.split() method to split the string.
       Obj obj = new Obj();

       obj.Name = strlist[0].ToString();
       obj.Email = strlist[1].ToString();
       obj.Phone  = strlist[2].ToString();
       obj.othername = strlist[3].ToString();
       obj.company = strlist[4].ToString();
}
}
```

Above code works if all the delimiters are put exactly but doesn't work when given dynamically like the above. Any possible solution for this?

Comment: What is "doesn't work", what happens, and what do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean the column names can differ, and the data you're looking for can be in another position?

Comment: No, I meant if the given text file only has data of two columns it doesn't work. If the text file has only 2 columns then they will not be readed

Comment: c# 4.0? really?

Comment: Check the array length before using a specific index to make sure you are not getting an Index out of Range exception.

Comment: @VDWWD but I will be getting different number of data. Only the header will be fixed.

Comment: That's why saying "dynamic" should be forbidden. So your problem is that not every line has exactly 4 pipe characters. In that case, check your array length (`strlist.Length > 1 ? strlist[1] : null`). Also, what's with the upvotes? Winter Bash again?

Comment: That's why you should check the length, as @CodeCaster demonstrates. But if the length differs every time you will have a hard time knowing if index 2 is phone, email or company etc.

Comment: @VDWWD the headers appear to be fixed, see the last line `jane||98485|` with an empty element for email.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes not every line has 4 pipe character, but the mapping should be done correctly like in the above example in the third column, name - jane , phone - 98485 and the rest all fields should be empty.

Comment: @VDWWD the headers are fixed, but the data is not fixed. If there is not data for fields then it will be empty like jane| |98485. The object will be the same as header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any control over this, you should use a better serialization techinology, or at least use a csv parser that can deal with this sort of format. However, if you want to use `string.Split`, you can also take advantage of [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=net-5.0)

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default
> value if the index is out of range.

**Given**

```
public class Data
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string OtherName { get; set; }
   public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = File
   .ReadLines(SomeFileName)           // stream the lines from a file
   .Skip(1)                           // skip the header
   .Select(line => line.Split('|'))   // split on pipe
   .Select(items => new Data()        // populate some funky class 
   {
      Name = items.ElementAtOrDefault(0),
      Email = items.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
      Phone = items.ElementAtOrDefault(2),
      OtherName = items.ElementAtOrDefault(3),
      Company = items.ElementAtOrDefault(4)
   });


foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.Name}, {result.Email}, {result.Phone}, {result.OtherName}, {result.Company}");
```

**Output**

```
john, john@example.com, 1234, , example
doe, doe@example.com, , pin,
jane, , 98485, ,
```

Comment: what if this exists as a separate object like `public class Data { public Details details {get; set;} public OtherDetails otherDetails {get; set;}}` Will this work?

Comment: @ismav you would have to create those sub properties first

Comment: Can you please explain with some code, I can't figure it out. I'm a new dev.

Comment: @ismav `new Data() { details = new Details { Name = items.ElementAtOrDefault(0)}, ...`

Comment: Suppose there is a field with datetime type how to handle it? Like this                   `DOB = items.ElementAtOrDefault(11)` where DOB is of type datetime

Comment: @ismav `DOB = DateTime.TryParse(items.ElementAtOrDefault(11)??"", out temp)?temp: someDefault`

Answer (score 0):

When you split the line like `string[] strlist = line.Split('|');` you can get undesired results.
For example: `jane||98485|` generates an array of just 4 elements as you can check here https://rextester.com/WBOT6074 online.

You should check your array `strList` after generating it with thinks like measuring the size.
As you haven't given clear details about the problem I cannot give a more especific answer to it.

Comment: Edited the question, so you can understand better

Comment: Have you tried if this is the problem? It would be helped full if you tell us what kind of problem are you having when you say that your code just don't work.